# error: Error: Unable to resolve module `fs` from `App.js`: fs could not be found within the project

Tags: react-native, nodes

I am getting an error in the react native project. I am trying an example of pdf parser I have attached an example link. But I'm getting an error fs module not found within the project file.

error: Error: Unable to resolve module `fs` from `App.js`: fs could not be found within the project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to `fs` in react native. You need to use a library that uses the native filesystem api

Comment: any reference for native file system API? and how can apply for fs access in react native?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

Comment: But depending on what you are trying to achieve, you might be better of using a database

Comment: I have a pdf file. how can I read data from that pdf file?

Comment: how to use local path in this RNFS?

Answer (score 0):

You cant use just the fs library in react native, you have to use this [rn-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) for handling fs operations

Comment: I have a pdf file. how can I read data from that pdf file?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf try. this

Comment: basically, what I want to, I have a pdf file and I want to get data from that pdf file. I want a pdf parser example.

Comment: I have tried this lib.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-parse
but I am getting error. fs module not found.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs

In this lib how can I use my PDF local file path?